# Как выразить x с уравнения?

Tags: математика

Как выразить x из данного уравнения: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так, как я понимаю, т.е. через замену переменной и решения квадратного уравнения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В квадратном уравнении перед корнями должно быть рано 0.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, виноват, скопировал и забыл там на 0 заменить

Comment: @Zhihar У вас не прописан в правой части нет 0, и на фото решение как будто ноль есть

Comment: @Василь, да я потом увидел эту опечатку, там конечно 0 должен быть

Comment: Заметим в скобках, что со знаками + и - вы получаете под логарифмом числа x и 1/x, так что внутри выражения перед радикалом вы можете написать просто плюс, а плюс-минус вынести перед логарифмом. Так будет более очевидна симметрия решения в смысле знака...

Answer (score 4):

Обратный гиперболический косинус.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Домножьте левую и правую часть на e<sup>x</sup> и решите квадратное уравнение...